# How to create a SQL Server table with a column and its values to be generated automatically as a GUID

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I need to design a table in SQL Server having some columns, one of these columns (`ID` column and use sequential uniqueidentifier) should automatically populate its data when inserting other column data.

The values of the `ID` column should be generated automatically when insertion happens.

Please help me to do this, any help is appreciated.

NB: I am new to this step by step approach will be more helpful

Comment: In columns properties set it's increment value by `1`

Comment: in default value of that column write this newid().and let data type be uniqueidentifier

Comment: @KumarHarsh: if you want (pseudo-)sequential GUID's, you need to use `newsequentialid()` as the default (**not** `newid()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a table with a column `ID` of datatype `uniqueidentifier` and set it's default value to `newsequentialid()`:

[image]

Then, when you go insert rows into that table, just **omit** the `ID` column from the list of columns you're inserted values into:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(ColA, ColB, ....., ColX)
VALUES(.., .. ,. ...)
```

If you don't explicitly insert a value into `ID`, the default specification (`newsequentialid()`) will be used .

Comment: Thanks,I just forgot.

Comment: clearly explained and i got it and very thanks for that

Comment: @user2054137: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 3):

As per Marc_s's comment, you should use NEWSEQUENTIALID()

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (ColumnA uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID());
```

See [NEWSEQUENTIALID (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx)